# Find and replace complex term in a string using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I Need to wrap any expression in a string (it can be multiline string with many expressions, mixed with regular words) that starts with `abc.(efg|xyz).bar.` with curly braces.

I'm using find and replace approach using the following Regex:

```js
const MY_REGEX = /"?(?<![a-zA-Z0-9-_])((?:abc\.(efg|xyz\.bar))(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)+)"?/gm
someInput.replace(MY_REGEX, '{{$1}}')
```

My strategy works fine for simple cases like this:

```js
const input = 'abc.efg.bar.name.first, abc.xyz.role, non.captured.term' 
// outputs: {{abc.efg.bar.name.first}}, {{abc.xyz.role}}, non.captured.term
```

But fails miserably for a complex inputs like this one:

```js
const input = 'abc.xyz.bar.$func(foos[param[name="primary" and bool=true]].param[name="new"].multiValue)' 
// outputs: {{abc.xyz.bar.}}$func(foos[param[name="primary" and bool=true]].param[name="new"].multiValue)
// Should be: {{abc.xyz.bar.$func(foos[param[name="primary" and bool=true]].param[name="new"].multiValue)}}
```

I'm looking for a more robust way or better regex to do it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the desired result? What is the actual delimiter between each expression that should be wrapped? If you want to match balanced brackets, regular expressions are not generally the solution.

Comment: any term within a string that starts with `abc.xyz.bar.` or `abc.efg.bar.` should be wrapped with double curly braces. the actual delimiter between terms or words is whitespace.

Comment: How is the end of a "term" defined?

Comment: Why does it work miserably for the second input? What are you expecting, what do you get instead?

Comment: Have a look in the examples above i demonstrated the outputs in the end of each example with comment.

Comment: That's the actual output, you need to show what you want instead.

Comment: For the first example the output is exactly what i want.
For the second one it should be:


`{{abc.xyz.bar.$func(foos[param[name="primary" and bool=true]].param[name="new"].multiValue)}}`

Comment: Why is `abc.xyz.role` replaced with `{{abc.xyz.role}}`? It doesn't have `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples you gave, it looks like `,` should be the delimiter between expressions. So `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)+)` to `[^,]*` to match everything until the next `,`.

```js
const MY_REGEX = /"?(?<![a-zA-Z0-9-_])((?:abc\.(efg|xyz\.bar))[^,]*)"?/gm;
console.log('abc.xyz.bar.$func(foos[param[name="primary" and bool=true]].param[name="new"].multiValue)'.replace(MY_REGEX, '{{$1}}'));
console.log('abc.efg.bar.name.first, abc.xyz.role, non.captured.term'.replace(MY_REGEX, '{{$1}}'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm sorry my examples were misleading and not good enough.
The correct rules should be:
1. anything that starts with `abc.(efg|xyz\.bar).` meaning either abc.efg OR abc.xyz.bar.

2. the delimiter is not `,` It's only one example in fact the correct delimiter between terms is one or more whitespace and the string can also be multiline. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: The delimiter can't be whitespace. You have `name="primary" and bool=true` in the term, and it contains whitespace.

Comment: `abc.xyz.role` doesn't start with `abc.efg` or `abc.xyz.bar`

Comment: Apologies again... it should be `abc.xyz.` OR `abc.efg.bar.` I will update examples above to prevent any confusion again.

Comment: I think what you want can't be done easily with a regular expression. I think you're looking for something that will ignore the delimiters inside brackets, and regular expressions can't do this well.

Comment: OK, thank you so much for putting the effort. I will have to figure it out somehow.